# How do I call the constructor of a class' member?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I wanted to declare a `QGraphicsView` which has a previously declared member as an argument of the constructor, but the compiler interprets it as a function.

(Code for reference)

```
class Widnow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // constructors, member functions, etc...

private:
    Ui::Widnow *ui;
    QTimer timer01;
    QGraphicsScene gaem;
    QGraphicsView wiev(&gaem); //this gets interpreted as a function
}
```

Trying to call the constructor as `QGraphicsView wiev = QGraphicsView(&gaem);` also causes an error, as the copy constructor has been deleted... Is there a way to declare this member without errors?

Comment: Another solution is this : `QGraphicsView wiev{ &gaem }`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ compiler thinks that it is a method declaration where "wiev" as method that returns an instance of QGraphicsView. Use this way

```
class Widnow : public QMainWindow
{
 private:
    QGraphicsScene gaem;
    QGraphicsView wiev; //this gets interpreted as a function

   public:
     Widnow() : wiev(&gaem)
     {}
};
```

Comment: @Daniele suggestion is better as it uses direct initialization